# JSONObject parse dictionary objects

Tags: java, android, json, object

JSON values that I get from server:

```
{
"Status":0,
"Message":"",
"Result":{"0B":"S.C. Blue Air","0Y":"FlyYeti","1X":"Branson Air"}
}
```

Getting the result as 'response' after connection and I am able to show my `JSON` string results on the screen.

```
 JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
 String status = json.getString("Status");
 String message = json.getString("Message");
 String result = json.getString("Result");
 responseView.setText("Status" + status+ "Message" + message" + Result" + result);
```

I am okay the results of "Status" and "Message" but not with "Result" because want to separate "Result" objects as  and able use each of them as objects.

For example:
When I type **OB** in my app, I will get the result **S.C. Blue Air**

Comment: Your `Result` is json object and you are parsing it as string...correct it

Comment: You can use Pretty Print JSON Output (Jackson).

Comment: you need to grab the result object, then grab the strings from that

Comment: I think it is better for you to use libraries such as gson or moshi, that make the parsing for you and you only have to annotate your models.

Comment: could you please give me some examples that close to my issue? @droidpl

Comment: Sure, let me write one in this post

Answer (score 3):

Instead of :

```
String result = json.getString("Result");
```

use

```
if(json.get("Result") instanceof JSONObject){
    JSONObject object = (JSONObject) json.get("Result");
    //do what you want with JSONObject
    String ob = object.get("0B");

}
```

If you want to store it some way you can put it to `Map` or create object if always it is same data

Comment: my result is a object. But how can I access OB and S.C. Blue Air objects separately. Should I put the object in a hashmap?

Answer (score 2):

You can use some libraries such as [Gson (Google)](https://github.com/google/gson) or [Moshi (Square)](https://github.com/square/moshi)
Those libraries allows you to declare your model as a plain java class (commonly called POJOS) annotated in some way that this libraries bind your properties in the JSON to your java properties.

In your case:

JSON:

```
{
"Status":0,
"Message":"",
"Result":{"0B":"S.C. Blue Air","0Y":"FlyYeti","1X":"Branson Air"}
}
```

MODEL:

```
public class MyCallResponse {
    @SerializedName("Status")
    int status;
    @SerializedName("Message")
    String message;
    @SerializedName("Result")
    Result result;
}

public class Result {
    @SerializedName("0B")
    String b;
    @SerializedName("0Y")
    String y;
    @SerializedName("0X")
    String x;
}
```

In this case, with Gson you can do:

```
MyCallResponse response = new Gson().fromJson(json, MyCallResponse.class);
Log.i("Response b", response.result.b);
```

Look at the documentation for more information about both libraries.

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(response);
JSONObject resultObj = json.getJSONObject("Result");
String OB = resultObj.getString("OB");
```

Comment: It works but I want to call OB on my app as a user not in code. So I think I have to put the objects in a map or something like that for being able to call, search or anything. Do you agree with me?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String base = ""; //Your json string;
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(base);
JSONOBject resultJson = json.getJSONObject("Result");

// Get all json keys "OB", "OY", "1X" etc in Result, so that we can get values against each key.
Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = resultJson.entrySet();

Iterator iterator = entrySet.iterator();

for (int j = 0; j < entrySet.size(); j++) {
    String key = null; //key = "OB", "OY", "1X" etc
    try {
        Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) iterator.next ();
        key = entry.getKey ().toString ();
      //key = "OB", "OY", "1X" etc
    }
    catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    if (!TextUtils.isEmpty (key)) {

        Log.d ("JSON_KEY", key);
        String value = resultJson.getString(key);
        //for key = "0B", value = "S.C. Blue Air"
        //for key = "0Y", value = "FlyYeti"
        //for key = "1X", value = "Branson Air"
    }
}
```

It works with any array with dynamic json key.

Don't forget to [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) & upvote if it works.

Comment: Set<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> entrySet = resultJson.entrySet();          I am having red error in entrySet() and still couldn't figure out :/